# Shell Script To CD and Run a Python Script

Tags: linux, shell-script, alias, bashrc, cd-command

OK, I know that there is a lot like this question but I literally get nothing.
The thing i need is a script that cd's to `/home/project` then runs `python3 pyscript.py`
I created an alias to cd `alias name='cd /home/project` but when I run a shell script I get an error:

`: not found: 3: script: script.sh: name 
' [Errorno 2] No such file or directory
: not found: 5: script.sh`

My sh script is:

`#!/bin/bash
name
python3 pyscript.py`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why do you need it to cd to the directory? why not just run it straight from there e.g `/home/project/pyscript.py`

Comment: Don't we need python3 front of pyscript.py to run it. I changed script to /home/project/pyscript.py (I think you meant this) then it gave: `not found 3:` `not found 4:`

Comment: @DeclanGallagher We don't know if the script uses relative paths, in which case it would have to run with a particular working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your `bash` is the unknown command `name`.  I don't know what your intention with this command is, so I can not comment further on it.

---

To run your Python script with `/home/project` as the working directory, directly on the command line:

```
( cd /home/project && python3 pyscript.py )
```

The command is in parentheses so that the `cd` does not affect the working directory of the interactive shell session.

As an alias:

```
alias mypyscript='( cd /home/project && python3 pyscript.py )'
```

As a shell function:

```
mypyscript () (
    cd /home/project && python3 pyscript.py
)
```

As a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/project && python3 pyscript.py
```

In all of the above, `python3 pyscript.py` would not be invoked if the `cd` failed.

Comment: So I changed lines to `cd /home/project && python3 pyscript.py` but its still giving me `Errorno 2 no such file or directory`. I'm 100% sure that path to directory is correct. Also sorry for bothering you with this easy problem.

Comment: @AKKaygin That's the error that Python gives when it can't find the script file. You should look at the contents of `/home/project` to make sure that the script file `pyscript.py` lives there and that you are spelling the name of it correctly.